# Comparing Sums SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to do a simple problem and I am getting stuck.

I have a table

```
S# Sname StatusNum  City
s1 Smith 20         London                   
s2 Jones 10         Paris                    
s3 Blake 30         Paris                    
s4 Clark 20         London                   
s5 Adams 30         Athens
```

I am trying to show which city has a greater StatusNum than Paris. This is what I have done so far.

```
Select sum(StatusNum) as sales_num, city
From S
Group by city
Having sum(StatusNum) > 40;
```

Now I want to acheive the same result but not having manually add the numbers up myself and using the greater than 40, rather find the sums than compare them. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Having sum(StatusNum) > (select paris sum...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include aggregation to only sum values for a specified city.

```
Select sum(StatusNum) as sales_num, city
From S
Group by city
Having sum(StatusNum) > (Select sum(StatusNum) From S where city = 'Paris')
```

Comment: So this will show items that have a lower value than Paris, I am trying to show only cities that have a higher value than Paris. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: @R_Lothbrok .. this shows items that have a higher value than Paris. is this not what you needed?

Comment: Paris when added together has 40. When I run this I see Athens (30), and London (40). Nothing should appear in the answer since technically nothing has a higher sum than Paris. @vkp

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much it has been driving me mad!

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this, and change ´Paris´ in the secondary query as you like:

```
Select sum(StatusNum) as sales_num, city
From S
Group by city
Having sum(StatusNum) > (Select sum(StatusNum) From S
                         Group by city
                         where city = "Paris");
```